# Mathematics Proof - prove that $p+q > \sqrt{4pq}$

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

I want to ask about a question I found in a mathematics textbook today in my lecture.

This was the question:

> Prove that for any positive numbers p and q:
> $p+q > \sqrt{4pq}$

Now, this is what I did.

I worked backwards to find an expression $f(x) > 0$

$$p+q > \sqrt{4pq}$$
$$(p+q)^2 > 4pq$$
$$(p+q)^2 - 4pq > 0$$

So, I looked at the expression $(p+q)^2$.

I know that adding two producing numbers and squaring them means that the result will be greater than zero, so $(p+q)^2 > 0$

Now, I also noted that $(p+q)^2$ or better shown as $p^2 + 2pq + q^2$ is greater than $4pq$ so I thought in the end, this must mean that
as

$$(p+q)^2 > 4pq$$

I can show hence that

$$p+q > \sqrt{4pq}$$

However, the book gives this very strange answer. I will attach it as a picture for reference.

[image]

> $(p+q)^2 = p^2 + 2pq + q^2 = (p-q)^2 + 4pq$
>
> $(p-q)^2 ≥ 0 $ since it is a square, so $(p+q)^2 ≥ 4pq$
>
> $p > 0, q > 0 \Rightarrow p + q > 0 \Rightarrow p+q > \sqrt{4pq}$

I'm confused. What is the book trying to say, and is my answer a valid proof?

many thanks.

Comment: How did you note that $(p+q)^2>4pq$ or $p^2+2pq+q^2>4pq$

Comment: The proof in the book has three lines. The first two lines justify rigorously your observation that $(p+q)^2=p^2 + 2pq + q^2$ is greater than $4pq$ (a valid proof requires a rigorous argument). The last line justifies that square root of $(p+q)^2$ is ideed $p+q$ (if $p+q$ is negative, then $\sqrt{(p+q)^2}$ is $|p+q|$ instead of $p+q$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote in your answer: I also noted that $(p+q)^2$ is greater than $4pq$. But that is actually not obvious. To prove that you need to say that $(p-q)^2>0$ (since it's a square), hence $p^2 -2pq + q^2>0$ and adding $4pq$ to both parts we get the desired inequality.

Comment: Oh my lord, yes! Yes, thank you! I'm going to write my own answer now.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I also noted that $(p+q)^2$ or better shown as $p^2+2pq+q^2$ is greater than $4pq$ so I thought in the end, this must mean that as $(p+q)^2>4pq$.

This part of your proof makes no sense, and is where your proof is lacking.

Here's an explanation of the book's proof:

$$
\begin{align}
(p-q)^2 &\ge 0\tag{all squares are positive}\\
(p-q)^2 + 4pq &\ge 4pq\\
(p+q)^2 &\ge 4pq \tag{rearrange the left hand side}\\\
p+q &\ge \sqrt{4pq} \tag{take square roots}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Fantastic answer, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You did not prove that $(p+q)^2\geq4pq$.

If $(p+q)^2>0$ it not gives that $(p+q)^2\geq4pq$.

The book tries to say that from $(p+q)^2\geq4pq$ follows $p+q\geq\sqrt{4pq}$ if $p+q\geq0$.

For example $(-3)^2>4$ is true, but $-3>\sqrt{4}$ is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Book is right. You say:

$ p^2+q^2+2pq $ is greater than 4pq

From what you know this? It is the same you must prove.
and 
  $(p-q)^2 \geq 0 $ proves it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a simple inequality relation here,

Arithmetic Mean≥ Geometric Mean(AM≥GM)

Now consider two numbers $p$ and $q$

AM= ${p+q}/2$

GM=$\sqrt{pq}$

Since, AM≥GM

That's why,
${p+q}/2$≥$\sqrt{pq}$

OR,
${p+q}≥2\sqrt{pq}$

OR,
${p+q}≥\sqrt{4pq}$

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made the connection that $(p+q)^2\ge4pq\implies (p-q)^2\ge0$ obvious. Your proof is very close, but obfuscates this connection, which is the heart of the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I did not actually answer the question.

Considering this all again, we know that $(p-q)^2 > 0$ because it is a square number, hence

$$p^2 + q^2 - 2pq > 0$$

so $$p^2 + q^2 + 2pq > 4pq$$
$$(p+q)^2 > 4pq$$
$$p+q > \sqrt{4pq}$$

Comment: Wrong again.  We know ${(p-q)}^2\ge0$.   Note the equals!

Answer (score 0):

## Counter-example

The book got it right, but your statement is in fact **false**.

The book proved $p+q\ge\sqrt{4pq}$

You wrote $p+q\gt\sqrt{4pq}$

It turns out if $p=q$ the equation becomes $p+p\gt\sqrt{4pp}$ or $2p\gt2p$ which is false.  It turns out your statement is true only for $p\ne q$.